# Vuejs Multiple Components without Webpack

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a website which has static pricing tables. I am trying to convert them into multiple components in Vuejs. So Page 1 will have a component 1 displaying the prices for that particular page, page 2 will have its own component and so on. I have created a template with the `<template id="abc"></template>` tag.
Below is the code:

```
Vue.component('pb-wp', {
template:'#package1',
data: function(){
    return {
          package1: [
            {
              id: '4',
              name: 'Some title 1',
              priceNew: 249,
              priceOld: 399
            },
            {
              id: '5',
              name: 'Some title 2',
              priceNew: 249,
              priceOld: 399
            }
    ],
    package2: [
                        {
                        id: '3',
                        name: 'Some New title 1',
                        priceNew: 249,
                        priceOld: 399
                      },
                      {
                        id: '2',
                        name: 'Some New title 2',
                        priceNew: 249,
                        priceOld: 399
                      }
        ],
    }
}
});

new Vue({
 el: '#pricing'
});
```

In HTML:

```
<pb-wp></pb-wp>
```

Can I pass multiple instances in the template and Vue.component like:

```
Vue.component('pb-wp', 'pb-wp2' {
template:['#package1', '#package2'],
data: function(){
    return {...}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the data for each pricing-table-instance within your component, make the component data-independent and put the data in the parent Vue instance which calls the component.

e.g. change your component declaration to this:

```
Vue.component('pb-wp', {
    template:'#package',
    props: {
        package: {
            type: Object,
            default: null,
        }
    }
});
```

Then you have your package, which could look something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="package">
    <div v-if="package">
        <h1>{{ package.name }}</h1>
        <div>
            Price: {{ package.priceNew }} 
            <span style="text-decoration: line-through">{{  package.priceOld }}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Instantiating Vue like this, with the data

```
new Vue({
    el: '#pricing',
    data: function() {
        return {
            package1: [
                {
                  id: '4',
                  name: 'Some title 1',
                  priceNew: 249,
                  priceOld: 399
                },
                {
                  id: '5',
                  name: 'Some title 2',
                  priceNew: 249,
                  priceOld: 399
                }
            ],
            package2: [
                {
                    id: '3',
                    name: 'Some New title 1',
                    priceNew: 249,
                    priceOld: 399
                },
                {
                    id: '2',
                    name: 'Some New title 2',
                    priceNew: 249,
                    priceOld: 399
                }
            ],
        }
    }
});
```

And then in HTML, you can use the components with the data

```
<div id="pricing">
    <h2>All Packages from 'package1'</h2>
    <div v-for="package, index in package1" :key="package.id + index">
        <pb-wp :package="package"></pb-wp>
    </div>
    <h2>All Packages from 'package2'</h2>
    <div v-for="package, index in package2" :key="package.id + index">
        <pb-wp :package="package"></pb-wp>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps to clarify the way Vue components work.
For reference, see:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#X-Templates